# How to apply the same Background-image in different desktop devices

Tags: css, background, position, background-image, background-position

how can i apply the same Backgrond image position for my image in different desktop devices?

This is the page where there is the background image : http://tommywebdesigner.com/Vision%20General.html

Here my code:

```
#vision {
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url("/img/lapedrera.jpeg");
background-position: 85% 62%;
box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 0 #888888 inset;
height: 350px;
margin-top: 35px;
width: 100%;
```

}

If you have a look by this tool http://quirktools.com and paste the url, you see that in different desktop devices the background-image change the position, how can i make my image having the same position as background-image in different desktop devices?

Hope the explanation is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understand your question correctly. If you want the image to display the same area regardless of how much you scroll down, you'll have to remove this attribute:

background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: You can set the to: background-position: center 1115px; Then you can keep the background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: Ok, cool it seems working right, could you explain me the meaning of that? thanks a  lot

Comment: You set the background-position to a percentage value. That measures the size of the visiting browser. The center value tells the image display centered inside the div element. The 1115px tells where on the y-axis to start showing the image. In this way, you're able to make it look the same in different screen resolutions.